# Apple falling from a tree NETLOGO

Tags: netlogo

How can I make an apple fall from a tree? I created the shape "apple" already, and I have the two main element (a tree and an apple) but they're not linked to each other. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share the code you’ve written?

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like a homework problem I'll just get you started.
NetLogo is not a gaming platform so it doesn't have "sprites" or collision-detections built in.  You have to do all the math yourself.

You need to reset the x and y coordinates of your apple each iteration of the GO step.

Here's the key equations you will need:

;; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body
;; distance fallen = 1/2  g  t^2

```
  set distance-fallen    0.5 * 9.8 * time * time ;; in meters and seconds
  set height ( branch-height - distance-fallen )   
  set ycor height
```